# Why does Ruby Array slicing sometimes returns nil and sometimes returns empty Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I got this question when doing ruby koans. Given this array:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`array[4, 0]` equals `[]`. However, `array[5, 0]` equals `nil`.

Both 4 and 5 are out of index. Why do they return different things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter of [Array#slice(start,length)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) is the place **between indices** where slicing should begin :

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# elements            : [   1   2   3   4   ]
#                         ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑
# slice start indices :   0   1   2   3   4
```

`slice(0,_)` begins left of `1`, `slice(3,_)` begins left of `4`, and `slice(4,_)` begins at the last possible place : right of `4`.

`slice(4,0)` is still inside `array`, it's the empty Array right of `4`.

`slice(5,0)` isn't inside `array` anymore, it's `nil`.

Comment: This design decision totally violates the principal of least astonishment

Comment: @JeremiahRose: It's true that it might be surprising at first. Also : "in a May 2005 discussion on the newsgroup comp.lang.ruby, Matsumoto attempted to distance Ruby from POLA, explaining that because any design choice will be surprising to someone, he uses a personal standard in evaluating surprise. " from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language).